# python object to native c++ pointer

Tags: c++, python, boost, embedded-language

Im toying around with the idea to use python as an embedded scripting language for a project im working on and have got most things working. However i cant seem to be able to convert a python extended object back into a native c++ pointer.

So this is my class:

```
class CGEGameModeBase
{
public:
    virtual void FunctionCall()=0;
    virtual const char* StringReturn()=0;
};

class CGEPYGameMode : public CGEGameModeBase, public boost::python::wrapper<CGEPYGameMode>
{
public:
    virtual void FunctionCall()
    {
        if (override f = this->get_override("FunctionCall"))
            f();
    }

    virtual const char* StringReturn()
    {
        if (override f = this->get_override("StringReturn"))
            return f();

        return "FAILED TO CALL";
    }
};
```

Boost wrapping:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(GEGameMode)
{
    class_<CGEGameModeBase, boost::noncopyable>("CGEGameModeBase", no_init);

    class_<CGEPYGameMode, bases<CGEGameModeBase> >("CGEPYGameMode", no_init)
        .def("FunctionCall", &CGEPYGameMode::FunctionCall)
        .def("StringReturn", &CGEPYGameMode::StringReturn);
}
```

and the python code:

```
import GEGameMode

def Ident():
    return "Alpha"

def NewGamePlay():
    return "NewAlpha"


def NewAlpha():
    import GEGameMode
    import GEUtil

    class Alpha(GEGameMode.CGEPYGameMode):
        def __init__(self):
            print "Made new Alpha!"

        def FunctionCall(self):
            GEUtil.Msg("This is function test Alpha!")

        def StringReturn(self):
            return "This is return test Alpha!"

    return Alpha()
```

Now i can call the first to functions fine by doing this:

```
const char* ident = extract< const char* >( GetLocalDict()["Ident"]() );
const char* newgameplay = extract< const char* >( GetLocalDict()["NewGamePlay"]() );

printf("Loading Script: %s\n", ident);
CGEPYGameMode* m_pGameMode = extract< CGEPYGameMode* >( GetLocalDict()[newgameplay]() );
```

However when i try and convert the Alpha class back to its base class (last line above) i get an boost error:

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to extract a C++ pointer to type class CGEPYGameMode from this Python object of type Alpha
```

I have done alot of searching on the net but cant work out how to convert the Alpha object into its base class pointer. I could leave it as an object but rather have it as a pointer so some non python aware code can use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stefan from the python c++ mailling list, i was missing

```
super(Alpha, self).__init__()
```

from the constructor call meaning it never made the parent class. Thought this would of been automatic :D

Only other issue i had was saving the new class instance as a global var otherwise it got cleaned up as it went out of scope.

So happy now

Answer (score 1):

May not be the answer you are looking for, but take a look at [ChaiScript](http://www.chaiscript.com/) for embedding in your C++ application.

According to their website,

> ChaiScript is the first and only
>   scripting language designed from the
>   ground up with C++ compatibility in
>   mind. It is an ECMAScript-inspired,
>   embedded functional-like language.
>
> ChaiScript has no meta-compiler, no
>   library dependencies, no build system
>   requirements and no legacy baggage of
>   any kind. At can work seamlessly with
>   any C++ functions you expose to it. It
>   does not have to be told explicitly
>   about any type, it is function
>   centric.
>
> With ChaiScript you can literally
>   begin scripting your application by
>   adding three lines of code to your
>   program and not modifying your build
>   steps at all.

Comment: That looks great. Just want something that can wrap c++ objects quickly. Ill give it a go tonight

Comment: Its good except i cant extend classes and then share that pointer with c++ :(

Comment: Lodle- as one of the developers of ChaiScript I was curious if you could expound on what you need to do with extending of classes? You can create and share functions as callbacks between C++ and ChaiScript, if that might meet your need.

Comment: @Lefticus i send an email to your website.

Comment: @lefticus Look at http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend it provide an easy way of extending objects, and probably of what Lodle is looking for. Anyway python is better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure whether it will help you, but I had the same problem with scripts in Lua. We created objects from Lua and wanted some c++ code to handle the objects via pointers. We did the following:

- all object stuff was written in c++, including constructors, destructors and factory method;
- lua code was calling a factory method to create an object. this factory method 1) gave the object a unique ID number and 2) registered it in the c++ map, that mapped ID numbers to native pointers;
- so, whenever lua was going to pass a pointer to c++ code, it gave an object ID instead, and the c++ code looked up the map for finding the actual pointer by ID.

Comment: this would be ok but i want the script to extend the object which makes this not so good