# Extract base class pointer

Tags: c++, python, object, boost, extract

I was told that I can extract reference to base class from any `boost::python::object`.

The simple code looks like:

```
// c++:
class Base {};

// Export Base into python module

// python:
class Der(Base):
   pass

//c++:
boost::python::object obj; // It points to some Der class object made from python
boost::shared_ptr<Object> temp = extract< boost::shared_ptr<Object> >(obj);
```

The last line fails with:

> TypeError: No registered converter was
>   able to produce a C++ rvalue of type
>   boost::shared_ptr from this
>   Python object of type Der

Is it possible to extract pointer for `Base` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355187/python-object-to-native-c-pointer) I've managed out my question. First of all, my `Base` class was exported into python this way:

```
bp::class_<Base, boost::noncopyable>("Base", bp::no_init)
```

I had to remove `bp::no_init`. Why? Look at next update (the answer in stackoverflow post I gave before):

```
class Der(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Der, self).__init__() # Add this!
```

That's it (: